# Easy_install the wrong version of python modules (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, python, easy-install

I installed Python 2.7 on my Mac. When typing "python" in terminal, it shows:

```
$ python
Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 20:17:05) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

The Python version is correct here.

But when I try to easy_install some modules. The system will install the modules with python version 2.6 which are not able be imported to Python 2.7. And of course I can not do the functions I need in my code. Here's an example of `easy_install graphy`:

```
$ easy_install graphy
Searching for graphy
Reading pypi.python.org/simple/graphy/
Reading http://code.Google.com/p/graphy/
Best match: Graphy 1.0.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/G/Graphy/Graphy- 1.0.0.tar.gz#md5=390b4f9194d81d0590abac90c8b717e0
Processing Graphy-1.0.0.tar.gz
Running Graphy-1.0.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/fH/fHwdy4WtHZOBytkg1nOv9E+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-cFL53r/Graphy-1.0.0/egg-dist-tmp-YtDCZU
warning: no files found matching '*.tmpl' under directory 'graphy'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'graphy'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'graphy'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '.'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found under directory '.'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.aux' found under directory '.'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
graphy.all_tests: module references __file__
Adding Graphy 1.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Graphy-1.0.0-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for graphy

Finished processing dependencies for graphy
```

So it installs graphy for Python 2.6.

Can someone help me with it? I just want to set my default `easy_install` Python version to 2.7.

Comment: What happens when you type `which python` and `which easy_install`? How did you install Python 2.7, how did you install `easy_install`?

Comment: Ma-Xiaolongs-MacBook-Pro-2:~ MaXiaolong$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
Ma-Xiaolongs-MacBook-Pro-2:~ MaXiaolong$ which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install

Comment: I just download the python 2.7 and install the python. But I have no idea how I installed easy_install.. I thought it comes with python.. I'm new to python, sorry about that. Can you help me to think about how to fix the problem? Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that your installation of setuptools is obsolete.

If you want your "easy_install" match your updated python version, follow these steps:

- Download the corresponding .egg file at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files
- Run it as if it were a shell script:   `sh setuptools-0.6c9-py2.7.egg`

This will install the new "easy_install" executable, compatible with your current version of python.

Hope this helps.

(more details at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#cygwin-mac-os-x-linux-other)

Comment: lols~~~~it works!!!!!really thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!I successfully did this several days ago and I also make easy_install works properly, but i tried hundreds of methods, i forgot which one make easy_install works properly T.T Unfortunately i reinstalled my mac just now = =! I was afraid of that I need to try hundreds times again. Luckily that I saw your answer now!!! thank you very much : )

Comment: There is no `.egg` file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you command+i a python file you can change which version you want the file to be opened with.

Comment: really thank you for your answer. But this doesn't solve my problem. My problem is not run the code with a wrong version. It's easy_install in the wrong version of python. Anyway, thank you all the same : )

Answer (score 0):

The solution by fjavieralba did not work for me. What did work was installing easy_install using the tarball.

1. Download tarball from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files (I placed it in /tmp/)
2. Extract it using the command `tar -zxvf setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz`
3. `cd /setuptools-0.6c11`
4. install it with the python I want easy_install to work with (2.7, which in my case was under `/usr/local/bin/python`.

This was with:

```
/usr/local/bin/python setup.py build
/usr/local/bin/python setup.py install
```

And finally I can use east_install to get the package I want. For python2.7:

```
easy_install-2.7 *NAME*
```

or, for python 2.6:

```
easy_install-2.6 *NAME*
```